# Contradiction to evolution

Tags: human-biology

It is said that evolution occurs according to requirement ..if it is true then women who really needs safety should be strong and men who don't should not be strong...isn't it contradictory?

Comment: Why don't men need safety? Evolutionary men were supposed to protect the woman while they are weak (pregnancy, caring for small children).

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

The result of an evolutive adaptation depends on different kinds of selective pressures. So, **the solution can be more complex that you may expect** and **there can be more than one solution to the same problem** as well.

To stick with the example you made. **One possible solution** could be to have stronger females (note that this is true for many species of insects for example) **another solution** could be to have cooperation among the two genders and have for example stronger males that protect the females.

Also, you have to take a broader look at the effect of one particular trait because its evolution doesn't need to answer only a single problem but to fit in a context. For example to have a bigger and stronger body can be a problem if you don't have enough food to sustain it, so that particular solution, that looks obvious at first, can lead to a suboptimal result in a determinate context and **can be counter-selected in the long run**.

Moreover, especially in the case of social animals, **the social context affect the evolution as well**. For example, you may have a society in which strong woman are less likely to have children because of some social rule rather than because of some strictly-environmental reason. If we as a society, again just an example, decide that only girls taller than 190cm shall reproduce, then after a few generations you will have selected that trait.

Finally, remember that **evolution doesn't propose the only "good" new traits, it proposes "random" ones**, you never know in advance whether they will be useful in future or not.